# Access ear's classpath from war

Tags: weblogic, war, ear

In weblogic app server I deployed EAR and WAR.

I want to know it WAR can access the jars defined in classpath of EAR (META-INF\Manifest.mf).

*And latter dynamically load them in war, but this is other matter...

Comment: The answer is yes.
But, you should avoid using Manifest.mf to define j2ee applications' classpath.
Put your jars in your ear in APP-INF/lib folder. They will be added to your application's classpath by WebLogic. Your war will have access to classes and resources located in these jars.

Comment: this issue is that I can't touch existing config, I can only deploy new war/ear. So I would like to know hos to do it based on your comment: 'The answer is yes'

Comment: Give more info about your situation and the issue.

Comment: I would like like to invoke some ejbs in ear from new war using lookup, remote/local interfaces but  war doesn't have the interfaces in classpath. So if I can load them from ear it would help...

Comment: Can you copy ejb's interfaces from deployed ear to your new ejb client application (war or ear) ?